# How to keep a PMD tooltip displayed in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pmd

I'm using the PMDPlugin (version 1.8.3) with Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2017.3.

After running PMD, hovering the mouse over a line in the PMD pane displays additional information in a tooltip with a yellow background. See the screenshot below for an example.

The problem is that the tooltip disappears after about two seconds. Selecting (clicking) the line first makes no difference; the tooltip still disappears.

I'd like the tooltip to remain displayed for more than a couple of seconds. Is there any way to configure tooltips to become "sticky", or adjust their lifetime in Intellij IDEA, or is this just a feature/limitation of the PMDPlugin?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such setting. Neither in PMD plugin or in IntelliJ IDEA currently. In IDEA you can set just initial delay before showing tooltips but not the duration.

The easiest way of reading details on the issue instead of tooltip is right clicking the issue and selecting 'Details'

[image]

It will redirect you to the webpage describing the type issue and the reasoning behind why it is bad, such as here:

> https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.8.1/pmd-java/rules/java/design.html#UseUtilityClass

Compared to the tooltip there is even more information about the issue such as detailed code samples.

Comment: Thanks. This approach is much better than what I was asking for anyway. I had tried selecting 'Details' from the menu and it didn't work for me, but apparently it only works for PMD messages that relate to specific lines in the code; there is no webpage linking for the parent PMD messages.

Comment: Also, I discovered that the tooltip will display permanently if you move the mouse within the line while the tooltip is displayed, but I suspect that is a bug rather than a feature.